# Mongoose Private Chat Message Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add private messaging between users into my data model.  I've been going back and forth between two possible ways of doing this.

1) Each user has an array of user_id, chat_id pairs which correspond to chats they are participating in. Chat model just stores chat_id and array of messages.

2) Don't store chats with user at all and just have the Chat model store a pair of user_ids and array of messages.

The issue with option (1) is whenever a user joins or starts a chat, I would need to look first through the array for the user to see if the user_id, chat_id pair already exists.  And then do a second find for the chat_id in Chat. If it doesn't exist, I would need to create the user_id, chat_id pair in two different places for both users who are participating.

With option (2) I would search through the Chat model for the user_id1, user_id2 pair, and if I find it I'm done, if not I would create a new Chat record for that pair and done.

Based on this option (2) does seem like the better way of handling this.  However, I'm running into issues figuring out how to model the "pair" of user ids in a way that they are easily searchable in the chat model.  i.e. how do I make sure I can find the chat record even if the user_ids are passed in the wrong order, i.e. user_id2, user_id1.  What would be the best way to model this in Mongoose?

```
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  messages: [{
        text: { 
          type: String,
          max: 2000
        },
        sender: { 
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'User'
        }
      }],
  participant1: [{                
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'User'
        }]
  participant2: [{                
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'User'
        }]
});
```

If it's something like above, how would I search for a participant pair?  Could I order the participant IDs in some way so that they are always participant1 < participant2 for example, making search simpler?

Comment: I would think you would want the sender how you have it and then instead of doing `participant1`, `participant2`,  etc. just do `participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]` which would give you an array of users and then to do a search you would do something like this `Chat.find({ participants: { $in: { "array of names" }}, function (err, participants) { }`

Comment: @gmaniac thanks! I think I'll end up doing something very similar to what you suggested. $in doesn't work, since that does an $or but $all does work for this I think.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you want to update your question we can help you further or if you find what you were looking for post the answer and accept it.

Comment: check this https://github.com/sibelius/semcomp-graphql/blob/master/src/model/Conversation.js

Answer (score 14):

Well, there is no correct answer to this question, But definitely, the approaches you have mentioned are not the best at all!

**Firstly, when you are thinking about designing a "chat" model, you need to take into account that there would be millions of messages between the users, so you need to care about performance when you want to fetch the chats.**

Storing the messages into an array is not a good idea at all, your model's size will be large by the time and you have to consider that MongoDB's document size limit is currently 16 MB per document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

**Secondly, You have to consider pagination aspect because it will affect the performance when the chat is large, when you retrieve the chat between 2 users you won't request all the chats since the beginning of the time, you will just request the most recent ones, and then you can request the older ones if the user scroll the chat, this aspect is very important and can't be neglected due to its effect on performance.**

***My approach will be to store each message in a separated document***

First of all, storing each message in a single document will boost your performance during fetching the chats, and the document size will be very small.

*This is a very simple example, you need to change the model according to your needs, it is just to represent the idea:*

```
const MessageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    message:{
        text: { type:String, required:true }
        // you can add any other properties to the message here.
        // for example, the message can be an image ! so you need to tweak this a little
    }
    // if you want to make a group chat, you can have more than 2 users in this array
    users:[{
        user: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', required:true }
    }]
    sender: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', required:true },
    read: { type:Date }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
```

***you can fetch the chats by this query:***

```
 Message.find(({ users: { "$in" : [#user1#,#user2#]} })
    .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
    .limit(20)
```

Easy and clean!
as you see, pagination becomes very easy with this approach.

Comment: You should make a new collection for conversation.In your schema,There are data  duplication.Let say It is a group of 100 member . So every document contain array of 100 member of ObjectId(User) . This stupid data will fill up your disk space faster !

Answer (score 11):

A few suggestions.

First - why store Participant1 and 2 as arrays?  There is one specific sender, and one (or more) recipients (depending on if you want group messages).

Consider the following Schema:

```
var ChatSchema = new Schema({
    sender : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'User'
    },
    messages : [
        {
            message : String,
            meta : [
                {
                    user : {
                        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                        ref : 'User'
                    },
                    delivered : Boolean,
                    read : Boolean
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    is_group_message : { type : Boolean, default : false },
    participants : [
        {
            user :  {
                type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref : 'User'
            },
            delivered : Boolean,
            read : Boolean,
            last_seen : Date
        }
    ]
});
```

This schema allows one chat document to store all messages, all participants, and all statuses related to each message and each participant.

the Boolean is_group_message is just a shorter way to filter which are direct / group messages, maybe for client side viewing or server-side processing.  Direct messages are obviously easier to work with query-wise, but both are pretty simple.

the `meta` array lists the delivered/read status, etc, for each participant of a single message.  If we weren't handling group messages, this wouldn't need to be an array, but we are, so that's fine.

the `delivered` and `read` properties on the main document (not the meta subdocument) are also just shorthand ways of telling if the last message was delivered/read or not.  They're updated on each write to the document.

This schema allows us to store everything about a chat in one document.  Even group chats.

Comment: Using this approach will make pagination for the chat inefficient

Comment: @Maysara I've implemented a more complex data schema for a production chat service based on this method, if requested I could take some time and share the process.  There are certainly tradeoffs with any choice.  Having each message stored individually and then aggregating them seems like the other alternative which doesn't make much sense to me.  
Reverse pagination is relatively rare in any chat system, and when it happens, pagination to the point where this *actually* becomes inefficient is really, Really rare.

Comment: @AugieGardner, i'm building a chat, but atm, i have a conversation schema and message schema, who have the ID of the conversation.
Your schema look very good, and prevent mutliple queries from MongoDB.
Can you show me the "more complex" schema that you are talking about ?