# How can I make a private message schema for mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a messages schema + routes for my backend. I want that two users can write a message to each other and the message has to be stored for both of them.

I made the the user-model-schema and the user-routes, they are working but I'm stuck with the messaging.

mongoDB should contain the message
how can I manage sending messages?

Here is what I tried so far

messages-route:

```
var express = require("express");
var User = require("../models/users.js");
var router = express.Router();
const message = require("../models/messages");

router.post("/:recipient", (request, response) => {
  User.find({
    username: [request.body.sender, request.params.recipient],
//   }, {
//       message: request.body.message
//   }, {
//     upsert: false,
//     new: true,
  })

    .then((users) => {
        users.forEach((user) => {
            user.updateMany({
                message: request.body.message
            })

        })
      response.status(200).json(users);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      response.status(500).json(error);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my messages-schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


var UserMessage = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { "type": mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, "ref": "User" },
    username: String,
    view: {
        inbox: Boolean,
        outbox: Boolean,
        archive: Boolean
    },
    content: {type: String},
    read: {
        marked: { "type": Boolean, default: false },
        date: Date
    }
});

var schemaMessage = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId({
    from: String,
    to: [UserMessage],
    message: String,
    created: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Messages", UserMessage);
```

I'm very unsure with the schema, I put in some suggestions I found here on stackoverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm now making a messages Schema, and i thought of something like this:

```
const ChatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    participants: [{type: mongoose.Schema.objectId, ref: "users"}],
    last_message: Number,
    _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.objectId}
    //...
})
```

Here you could use the same schema to make chat groups, and it will work having a separate document for each message with a field with the chatroom _id, so you could query them

And you might be thinking, why not put all the messages in an array on `ChatSchema`?
Well, because we don't want the users to recieve all their messages each time they enter a chat.

I know, you might be thinking about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499371/8937005) to prevent that over-load of data to the client

```
 MessageSchema.find(({ ... })
    .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
    .limit(20)
```

But here you're still recieving all the messages from the database to the server, and users could have even 1000 messages per chat, so an idea that came to my mind was making `MessageSchema` like this:

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    message: String,
    chatRoom_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.objectId},
    sentBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.objectId, ref: "users"},
    seenBy: [{ user: {type: mongoose.Schema.objectId, ref: "users"}, seen: Boolean }],
    numberOfMessage: Number
    //...
})
```

And the magic is with `numberOfMessage`, because you could query the MessageSchema with [comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) like this:

```
const currentMessage = 151 //this is the numberOfMessage number of the last message the user saw, and when the user scrolls up the chat you could send the numberOfMessage of the last loaded message.
//To know from wich numberOfMessage start, just use the ``last_message`` field from the chatroom's ``ChatSchema``


const quantityNewMessages = 10 //this is the quantity of new messages you want the user to recieve


MessageSchema.find({ 
    chatRoom_id, 
    numberOfMessage: 
        { $lt: currentMessage , $gte: currentMessage + quantityNewMessages } //we use less than operator because the user will always recieve the last message first, so the previous messages are going to have a numberOfMessage less than this first message
})
```

And it will return us an array of 10 messages, wich you can concat to the messages array you already have in your frontend.

take note:

1. With this `MessageSchema`, all the users will share the same document for each message, you could make a separate document of a message for each user in a chatroom, so each user can delete a message without affecting the others.
2. I don't recommend you saving a `username` field, because the user could change it's username and if he does that, you would have to update ALL message documents with that username to the new username, so just leave the ref and populate it
3. You shouldn't put the document object in the `to` field, make it a separate document and only save it's ref. But I don't recommend doing it that way either
4. Don't use `users.forEach` because it modifies the array, use `users.map` because it returns a new array and doesn't mutates the original array
5. I see you have a bug, you are asking the data with the returned variable of the `forEach( user => user.update(...) )`, it should be `map( user => UserSchema.update({ _id: user._id }) )`
   But still, looping an array and making a call to the DB each time is very expensive and will lag the server, so use something like the `ChatSchema` I showed you, because you could get the chatroom information, and with the _id of that chatroom, query the newest messages

**I've not tested this code, i'm about to do it. If you run into any problem feel free to comment**